# Non-empty compact subset of an open set?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am being asked to prove the following for some homework:

> Let $K$ be a nonempty compact subset of an open set $U\subset\mathbb C$. Show that there is $r>0$ such that $D(z,r)\subset U$ for any $z\in K$. Note that the $r$ does not depend on $z\in K$.

**My possible attempt at a proof and its flaw:**

So now that I have what I am trying to prove up on the wall, here is my attempt at a proof and its flaw. In class, we were given the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.4.6** Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of $C$. Suppose $A$ is compact and $B$ is
>   closed. Then there exist $z_0 ∈ A$ and $w_0 ∈ B$ such that $|z_0 − w_0| = dist(A, B)$. In other words,
>   the minimum of the set {|z − w| : z ∈ A, w ∈ B} exists.

My plan is to use this theorem to show that $dist(K, U^c)$ exists. Then, if I let $r = dist(K, U^c)$, that should show that $D(z,r) \subset U$. The issue is how do I show that $r = dist(K, U^c)>0$. Any advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does “$D(z,r)>0$” mean? That’s a subset of the plane, isn’t it?

Comment: Yeah. It's the open disk centered on the point $z$ with radius $r$. What I meant to say is how do I show that $r = dist(K, U^c) > 0$.

Comment: Take a sequence of points in $K$ with ever smaller distance from $U^c$, extract a convergent subsequence, and look at the distance of the limit point to $U^c$, I guess. Or maybe a sequence of pairs of points $(k_n,u_n)$, extract a convergenet sequence from the $k$’s, and show that the corresponding seq of the $u$’s is also convergent, and look at the distance between the two limits. I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 1.4.6 tells you that your $r$ is the distance between some point $z_0\in K$ and some point $w_0\in U^c$. Since $K\subseteq U$, the points $z_0$ and $w_0$ are distinct, so their distance is $>0$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I think my professor is looking for something a little more rigorous. Any idea how to make that argument better for my professor?

Comment: No, I can't psychoanalyze your professor. The answer looks completely rigorous to me.  Does your professor perhaps want you to explicitly quote trivial facts like "If one set is included in another then every element in the former set is distinct from every element in the complement of the latter" or "the distance between two distinct points in $\mathbb C$ is positive"? I suppose some people might call that "more rigorous", and they might be right if you've just recently learned these facts, but in most circumstances I'd call such quoting "padding" rather than "rigor".

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like something he would want. It is undergrad complex analysis, so as much as it is padding in general it would probably be useful for this question.